# Going through all :tokens in a URL without the ":"

Tags: javascript, regex

Imagine you have: `/users/:userId/goals/:goalId/list`.
I want to create an array with all :tokens in this string, without the ":".
I am doing this at the moment:

```
var tokens = [];
var elements = target.match(/:(\w*)/g);
for( var i = 0, l = elements.length; i < l; i ++){
  tokens.push( elements[ i ].substr( 1 ) );
}
```

Which feels ugly and awkward.
Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
var myRegexp  = (/(?::)(\w+)/g);
var test = "/users/:userId/goals/:goalId/list";

match = myRegexp.exec(test);
while (match != null) {
    alert(match[1]);
    match = myRegexp.exec(test);
}
```

**`(?::)`** Creates a Non-capturing group

Or you could also try:

```
"/users/:userId/goals/:goalId/list".replace(/\/\w*/g,"").split(':')
```

with output: `["", "userId", "goalId"]`

Answer (score 1):

I might have posted this before in some other shape but here's a tiny function for a better `match` with global flag and capture groups:

```
String.prototype.gmatch = function(regex) {
  var result = [];
  this.replace(regex, function() {
    var matches = [].slice.call(arguments, 1, -2);
    result.push.apply(result, matches);
  });
  return result;
};
```

And use it like:

```
var str = '/users/:userId/goals/:goalId/list'

var tokens = str.gmatch(/:(\w+)/g); //=> ['userId', 'goalId']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple `split` and `loop`

```
var test = "/users/:userId/goals/:goalId/list";

var s=test.split("/");

var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++){

    if (s[i][0] == ":"){
        result.push(s[i].split(":")[1]);
    }    
}

console.log(result);
```

Result:

```
["userId", "goalId"]
```

Comment: This is getting everything which is not desired. It is only necessary to get ":token" ==> userId and goalId

Comment: Can you please explain how your answer is better than others already posted?